# creating NFCNDEFPayload of NFCTypeNameFormat.media type in Swift

Tags: swift, nfc, payload, ndef, core-nfc

I am trying to create an instance of a NFCNDEFPayload with type NFCTypeNameFormat.media in Swift but I cannot find any sample codes.. (been googling for 4 hours now).. I am trying to create a NFCTypeNameFormat.media with type "text/plain" and a value like "Hello World".

btw I can now write NFCTypeNameFormat.nfcWellKnown successfully but I wanted to write in NFCTypeNameFormat.media as well

Hope anyone can help

Answer (score 0):

Ok I experimented some stuff and came up with this. Workin great for me

```
      let mediaRecord = NFCNDEFPayload.init(
                        format: NFCTypeNameFormat.media,
                        type: "text/plain".data(using: .utf8)!,
                        identifier: Data.init(count: 0),
                        payload: "Merry Christmas Everyone".data(using: .utf8)!,
                        chunkSize: 0)
```